# How would I make a reversed working link?

Tags: hyperlink

I've seen it before, it's a link placed in backwards form, and when you click it it goes to the site, but the correct way round. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean like this? [/moc.elgoog//:ptth](http://google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using HTML, the same way you'd make a regular link. Just put the URL backwards inside of the `<a>` element.

```
<a href="http://google.com/">/moc.elgoog//:ptth</a>
```